# Registering a Change Notification to an empty table oracle

Tags: database, oracle, queue

I am trying to register change notification listeners to a table, that, for the time being is empty. The only way in which I have seen to create table listeners is to select data into a specific variable:

```
SELECT employee_id 
    INTO   v_employee_id 
  FROM   hr.employees       
    WHERE  ROWNUM < 2;
```

The table here must have **at least** one row.

The full declaration:

```
DECLARE
  v_cn_recip       SYS.CHNF$_REG_INFO;
  v_regid          NUMBER;
  v_employee_id    hr.employees.manager_id%TYPE;
BEGIN
  v_cn_recip := SYS.CHNF$_REG_INFO('hr.dcn_callback­', DBMS_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION.QOS_ROWIDS, 0, 0, 0);
  v_regid := DBMS_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION.NEW_REG_START(v_cn_recip);
  SELECT employee_id 
    INTO   v_employee_id 
  FROM   hr.employees       
    WHERE  ROWNUM < 2;        
  DBMS_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION.REG_END;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('the registration id for this query is '||v_regid);
END;
/
```

From the Oracle documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_dcn.htm

My question is as follows: is there any way to register a change notification listener to an empty table? If not, was this done by design for any specific reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess, but according to the docs from the link you provided, it says:

> The DBMS_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION package registers the object itself,
>   which means that any change to the table—regardless of whether the
>   change is to the row returned by the registered query—generates a
>   notification

Which is strange you'd even need a query if its just registering the entire table, but maybe you can try doing a count from the table, which is guaranteed to return 1 and only 1 row:

```
DECLARE
...
v_num number;
...
BEGIN
...
SELECT count(1)
    INTO   v_num 
  FROM   hr.employees       
    WHERE  ROWNUM < 2;
...
END;
```

Comment: This works perfectly. It's just so peculiar that a query on the table is needed to be done register the listener. Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer this, I really appreciate it! I would publicly up vote if I could.